# Does adding "monotone" change the meaning?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I wonder why math texts states "function is monotone increasing/decreasing" instead of "function is increasing/decreasing" without word "monotone". Nothing changes, right? Then, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying *monotone increasing/decreasing* seems to me very imprecise. I'll discuss a different version of this, namely: *monotone (increasing or decreasing)*.

Mentioning it is monotone is sufficient. Adding (increasing or decreasing) is redundant. It's common practice in introductory books with the intent of making the reader rememeber what monotone means instead of (the reader) just skipping through the word.

I think a similar issue is this: *given a differentiable function $f$, consider it's derivative, $f'$*.

The first time I read something like that I was really confused. The way it is put, it looks like the author is singling out the usual derivative $f'$ from a set containing a bunch of possible derivatives of $f$, but of course, there's only one derivative of$f$.

Comment: Why is adding increasing or decreasing redundant? How are you supposed to know if the function is increasing or decreasing without writing it?

Comment: @Kaish In that case you use "increasing" instead of "monotone increasing".

Comment: @Kaish It is redudant because it is irrelevant. The only thing that matters if that it is monotone, i.e., either increasing or decreasing. For instance take an arbitrary integer $k$ (even or odd) ...

Comment: @GitGud Ahhh, ok, yeah that makes sense with that example. Thanks.